# Viewing power consumption of Android app

Tags: android, battery

There are dozens of questions related to fine-grained power monitoring in Android. Many of these use external tools and, as far as I can tell, it just isn't feasible yet to do so from within your average app. Is there any way to access the coarse grained value from the SDK instead? Android shows it in battery settings, e.g., "MyApp: 30%", but can apps directly read that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android shows it in battery settings, e.g., "MyApp: 30%", but can apps directly read that value?

Not through the Android SDK. There's probably a way to get that from some Linux `/proc` entry, but I don't know off the top of my head how.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's not what I wanted to hear -- seems silly that they won't let me touch even that statistic -- but it's good to know.